# Compare values of rows of datatable and list of tuples in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, tuples

I have a `datatable` in which one of the columns is `id1` and a list of integer tuples `List<Tuple<int,int>>`.

`datatable` column `id1` can have multiple values for a particular name. The list of tuple  is actually a reference list which contains all the ids `id1` as `tuple.Item1` and `id2` as `tuple.Item2`. I want to compare all the values of `id1` of `datatable` with the `id1` of list of tuple and only get all the corresponding `id2` from the list of tuple.

One way is first to get all the `id1` from datatable into a list and then compare with list of tuple like

```
var listOfid1 = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.field<int>("id1"))
    .ToList();
```

And now compare this `listOfid1` with the list of tuples and get all the corresponding `id2` w.r.t `id1`.

Can somebody help me to do this in one step, i.e. comparing all of the `id1` of the datatable with `id1` of tuple and get all the `id2` in a list?

Comment: Why you have one column `id1` but two items in the tuple? How are they related?

Comment: Change From : x.field<int>("id1")  To : x.field<Tuple<int,int,int>>("id1")

Comment: @Tim: this is because for a particular name we have multiple id1.And the list is just a ref data in which we have all the id1 and id2 irrespective of name. But now i want all the id2 for that name by conparing id1 of datatable and list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ`'s `JOIN`:

```
var id2Items = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
               join t in yourTupleList
               on row.Field<int>("id1") equals t.Item1
               select t.Item2;
List<int> id2List = id2Items.ToList();
```

Method syntax as requested:

```
List<int> id2List = table.AsEnumerable()
  .Join(yourTupleList, row => row.Field<int>("id1"), t => t.Item1, (r, t) => t.Item2)
  .ToList();
```

or with `Where` (less efficient) but maybe better readable:

```
List<int> id1List = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("id1")).ToList();
List<int> id2List = yourTupleList
  .Where(t => id1List.Contains(t.Item1))
  .Select(t => t.Item2) 
  .ToList();
```

Comment: :can u help me with converting it into lambda as i am a beginner in c# and linq?